# extract information with sed (s, n and g)

Tags: sed

I know that s means separate, but I can not figure it out here:

```
sed "s/<\/tr/\n<\//g;s/<\/font>/<\/font>\n/g"
```

could you please explain  what does that mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` doesn't mean separate, instead, it means substitute.

`\n` here means linebreak

`g` is a flag of `s` command, which will do substitute on all matched occurrences

```
sed "s/<\/tr/\n<\//g;      :replace all </tr by (linebreak)</
s/<\/font>/<\/font>\n/g"   :replace all </font> by </font>(linebreak)
```

same as

```
sed 's@</tr@\n</@g; s@</font>@&\n@g'
```

if you want to add linebreak before `</tr>`, the sed line won't do that, you could do:

```
sed 's@</tr>@\n&@g; s@</font>@&\n@g'
```

here the `&` means referencing the matched part.